# Add on builder helper could not be installed because firefox cannot modify the needed file

Tags: firefox, windows-7, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying  to run the sample program for add-on Firefox.
from https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/xxxxxx/latest

When I try to do the "Test"
Its asking me to download:

=

Install Add-on Builder Helper

To test this add-on, please install the Add-on Builder Helper add-on

When I try to install I am getting the following error:

add on builder helper could not be installed because firefox cannot modify the needed file

can you please let me know how to resolve this.
I googled it but could not the solution form my case.
I found during my saerach that some said "please change the length of the package" I have no idea how to do that

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the installation for Add-On Builder Helper as administrator. Windows 7 is more restrictive with rights to the `Program Files` folder than previous versions of Windows; non-administrator users don't have write access to that folder tree.

Comment: This is my personal labtop and I am the adminstrator.. should I do anything else?  ..

Comment: As I said, run the installer as administrator. It's not the same thing (right-click on any executable, and you'll see `Run as Administrator` in the popup menu, even when you're running as an administrative user).

Comment: Ken thanks for the reply.I understood what you said but did not get how to do that. I started wfiefox.exe as administrator. I got the location of plug in: http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/addons/182410/add_on_builder_helper-1.4-fx.xpi I downloaded to desktop ..I di dnot get how to run this as administor

Comment: And what do you do with it after it's been downloaded to the desktop? (Actually, why are you downloading it there in the first place? Win7 has a `Downloads` library that you have read/write access to even when not running as an administrator.)

Comment: You tried *what*? I can't see your screen from here, or read your mind. Please actually say what "I tried that" means.

Comment: I Downloaded that to "downloads" folder. when to firefox-- > install extensions from file. Same error. Than I closed Firefox and did open as administrator (for firefox.exe) and stil get the same error. please let me know if I am not clear

Comment: Sorry. Without more info about the error, I don't have any more suggestions. You might try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see where it's trying to write when the error happens, and then temporarily allowing access to that folder to all users during the install (depending on where that folder is, I'd probably remove it afterwards if I could).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16469/discussion-between-the-learner-and-ken-white)

Comment: @KenWhite: I am pretty sure that no Firefox extensions (including Add-on Builder Helper) require administrator privileges to install. No need to use Process Monitor by the way: the directory in question is `extensions` in the [Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).

Answer (score 0):

It might be this:

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jetpack/Release_Notes/1.0#Known_Issues

The first known issue there highlights a weakness on Windows where very long path names prevent installation. Unsure how long the path to your profile is. See this Mozilla support article for more info on profile directory locations:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?s=location+of+profile&r=1&as=s